# Using Google Sheets Source Plugin in GCP Datafusion, gives a 403 Forbidden error in Directory Identifier, service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

Need to pull a Google sheet through Datafusion.

There is [some documentation](https://github.com/data-integrations/google-drive/blob/develop/docs/GoogleSheets-batchsource.md) but it does not provide a practical example of how to configure the fields.

Currently I am receiving a 403 Forbidden error in Directory Identifier, service account details space, though all access is provided.

Comment: Updated the parameters and tried Validation.  The Directory Identifier field gives the following error, even though the GSheet has public visibility - 403 Forbidden { "code" : 403, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "reason" : "insufficientPermissions" } ], "message" : "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." } Provide an existing folder identifier.

Comment: Please add all additional information to your question. It will be more visible in question than comment. Could you provide which steps did you follow? When you received this issue?

Comment: @PjoterS The Google Sheet source plugin has following input parameters (Mentioning the ones I have some confusing about- Directory Identifier\Filter\Authentication Type\Metadata Extraction.  
Among these Directory Identifier- inserted key from gdrive folder URL(Do we need to publish the directory/file?).  
Authentication Type-Service Account(The file itself is unrestricted).  
Filter-Gave the key from the actual file URL.  
Metadata File Name-Not sure, I am aiming the schema columns to be the sheet first row headers.  
the given error is appearing on validation in Directory and SA

Answer (score 0):

The error you mention is related to `Permissions`. `Service account` should have the proper `permission` to read from `Google sheet` and then to write to `BigQuery`. This is one of the setups where the sheet needs to be shared with the `service account` or the user who wants to access it.

I guess you won't be able to provide the whole configuration so I will advise you to check [Cloud Data Fusion Access Control Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/access-control) to set proper permissions to your needs.

Also please be aware that there are still improvements in progress regarding `CDAP` Google drive/sheet plugins, which can be found [here](https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/PLUGIN-632).

Comment: Permissions have been provided to the sheet, to the datafusion service account, to the compute service account required for running datafusion job, and the sheet is publicly hosted to enable least security requirements as well.  I presume the plugin needs some specific inputs which is causing the error listed above, but not able to find any specific write up on how to use it.

Comment: Did you provide the service account file path?